# Allow access to index.php and one public directory only, with nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration, webserver

I want to allow free access to `/index.php` as well as `/public folder` and all its subdirs. Unfortunately, whatever I try, **Nginx** still denying connection, for either me or my scripts (nested in the html template, they need to access to the public folder in order to get some ressources like `css`).

I get a `403` when I try to open `public`, like all other paths. However, everything is good with index.php (access is allowed). The Nginx process is handled by www-data, public folder has all good rights. Do I miss something?

Here is my nginx configuration :

```
server {

        server_name dev;

        listen  80;
        listen  [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        return  301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

server {

        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        server_name dev;
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
       ssl on;
        ssl_certificate ssl/dev.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key ssl/dev.nopass.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        #ssl_protocols TLSv1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;

        root /var/www/awesomeProject;
        index index.php;

        # deny everything that doesn't match another location
        location / { deny all; }

        location = / { } # need to allow GET / to internally redirect to /index.php

        location /index.php {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.sock;
        }

location = /public { allow all; }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Just `location /public {}` should work.

Comment: it does not :/ i can't understand what the matter is...

Comment: it says : [error] directory index of "/var/www/awesomeProject/public/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: dev, request: "GET /public/ HTTP/1.1", host: "dev"

Comment: You want listing or you want files from `/public`? Require some real file like `/public/style.css`

Comment: oh! `/public/style.css` works. I see now, i didnt know that listing was default prohibited... My bad, my confusion. Thank you @Alexey

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by the fact that listing directory is default prohibited in Nginx. Above configuration works for real file like `/public/style.css`.

Thanks to [@Alexey Ten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016033/alexey-ten)